# Any way to copy/paste formulas in a range of cells but keep absolute?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a matrix of data and each cell is a formula.  All cell formulas are relative, so when I copy and paste just below, the formulas are now off.

Here's what I know works:

- Change each cell's formula from relative to absolute
- Copy the text from each formula, then paste this text below

I don't want to go and F4 each part of every formula for dozens of cells.  Is there a way to copy paste a large batch but tell Excel to keep the exact formulas as written?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally do a bulk Find and Replace on the original range, replacing all "=" signs with a random text string which is guaranteed to not occur anywhere within those formulas, my usual choice being "##".

This converts all the formulas to text strings, after which you can paste the range before then performing the reverse Find and Replace, i.e. replacing "##" with "=", which coerces Excel into treating the strings as actual formulas once more.

Of course, if we're talking about a very large amount of formulas, i.e. several thousand, then this operation can take a while to perform, since not only is Excel required to carry out the Find and Replace on all strings, but also to calculate all the newly-created formulas.

Regards

Comment: Awesome, it's amazing how effective back-door thinking can be with Excel

Answer (score 0):

When pasting, right click and choose "Paste Special" and use "Paste Formulas" (the fx icon).

Edit: Ah, I realize now this only works for 'fully anchored' ($A$1) cell references.

Comment: That does not stop the pasted formulas being treated as relative to the original ones.